# Clipping timeline at certain frame

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

It it possible to prevent timeline cursor going further than the end frame? For example, I have only 100 frames, but the cursor can go to 105.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Playback* panel, enable the *Limit Playhead to Frame Range* option:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, moonboots!! It worked for dragging the slider with the mouse button! The only problem that remains -- the slider continue to move further than the end frame if i use keyboard hotkeys. Is there a way to fix that too?

Comment: What keyboard hotkeys?

Comment: Alt + Mouse Wheel UP or DOWN

Comment: yes, I don't know if this is supposed to work that way or if they have forgotten something  ;)

Comment: Thank you anyway!